# upload 400k records from CSV - angular2/Springboot

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, angular2-template

I am developing an application with front-end in Angular2 and backend in Springboot .

I Have a project requirement wherein I have to upload 400k records from CSV to database ,but while uploading as per client demand I have to display all 400k records on UI .

Now My first question is , should I process the records in springboot or in angular itself .I personally want to achieve this on client side  if possible ?

Secondly I tried to achieve this , in angular but what happened  was I could extract all records from csv to an array in angular but when I started to iterate them using for / for of loop ,browser crashed in few seconds .

Please note :- after extracting records from CSV ,I have to each of them to check for certain validations .

Please let me know ,what is the best possible way to achieve it .

Comment: Seems like you are from India. Lakh is a unit understood in India and it's neighbors not much outside it. You should probably rename the title to say "4 Hundred Thousand" or 400K.

Comment: Upload your records in DB. Then fetch & display only limited records like 50 or 100 or 1000 per page Use paging You can't show 4L records on one page. Break them into pages.

Comment: Pagination is not possible as per current requirement

Comment: @TeaCode- any suggestion on my question ?

Comment: You cannot show 400K rows within a datagrid. The first question would be if your code (reading csv, validating rows) works in the browser without showing all the rows in the DOM (maybe only a progress bar). If this works you could try to show all the rows by using [Clusterize](https://github.com/NeXTs/Clusterize.js).